# what does wallclock mean in libsandbox?

Tags: sandbox

I am using `libsandbox` and there is this parameter in `quota` named `wallclock`.I googled and
found that it means time for which the program was active(ie. the `real time` displayed
when we do `./a.out` running executable of a program).

I am using it for an online judge , so how does the `wallclock` parameter vary from
program to program.What value should I give to it, and also if this time is exceeded what
error is thrown by the libsandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libsandbox` can apply two types of time limit to sandboxed programs, namely, `cpu clock` quota and `wall clock` quota. Both can trigger result code `TL` (time limit exceeded). Literally, `cpu clock` defines the processor time consumed by the sandboxed program, and `wall clock` measures the elapsed real-world time since the start of the sandboxed program.

The reason we need `wall clock` quota is that some programs (e.g. idle programs and I/O-intensive programs) may exhibit slow `cpu clock` consumption and remain alive for an undesirably long `wall clock` life time.

The recommended value for `wall clock` quota is 10x-15x that of the `cpu clock` quota.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of `libsandbox`.